# Can't remove cookie ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, cookies, web

I am using this code to remove my cookie...

```
public static void RemoveCookie(HttpRequestBase request, HttpResponseBase response, string cookieName)
    {
        if (request.Cookies[cookieName] == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName) { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d) };
        response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
```

On one page it works.  On another it does not.  If I look at developer tools the response cookie shows up as expired.  But it never removes that cookie.  Is there something could be causing this?

**Update:**
If I attempt to remove the cookie via javascript it works.  So as a workaround I implemented this on the client side...

```
@if (Model.RemoveFilterListCookie)
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.cookie = 'contentSetMediaListFilters=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
</script>
}
```

Comment: it should be response.Cookies.Remove(cookieName)

Comment: @KarthikGanesan - No because then it won't send back a response.

Comment: How do you use this method when it is called where uit failed?

Comment: @CodeNotFound - It's called during a GET request that includes an id.  The one where it works is also a GET request but it does not have an id.  That is the only difference that I can see.